# Missing ACPI tables on Linux Mint + Coreboot

Tags: linux, acpi, coreboot

I am using Linux Mint Linux version 5.15.0-76-generic on Lenovo Thinkpad x220 with flashed Coreboot BIOS.

System boots but with ACPI errors, namely:

```
[    0.194996] ACPI Error: AE_NO_ACPI_TABLES, While loading namespace from ACPI tables (20210730/tbxfload-68)
```

which comes from linux [tbsfload](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8689f4f2ea561dd080118eeb05c0255ac9542905/drivers/acpi/acpica/tbxfload.c#L68C12-L68C12) file.

The Lenovo x220 model has 1 USB 3.0 port (works fine) and 2 USB 2.0 ports.

USB 2.0 ports do not work which I believe is linked to the ACPI issue.

The boot time is around 1 minute because of USB failures:

```
[    3.431059] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
[   16.714718] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 2, error -110
[   16.714855] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 2, error -110
[   16.842692] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[   16.842732] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[   32.842692] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 3, error -110
[   32.842837] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 3, error -110
[   32.842953] usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle
[   32.842981] usb usb2-port1: attempt power cycle
[   33.286712] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[   33.286759] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[   44.106690] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 4, error -110
[   44.106832] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 4, error -110
[   44.234721] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[   44.234760] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[   54.858694] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 5, error -110
[   54.858846] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 5, error -110
[   54.858962] usb usb2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
[   54.859067] usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

I also do not have any visibility on battery state on Linux.

My question:
How do I provide ACPI tables to the OS so it does see it properly during boot?

Is it a matter of installing some missing packages on linux (if so, which ones?)
or rather is it coming from Coreboot (how can I fix the Coreboot build so `coreboot.rom` has necessary ACPI tables?).

I have reviewed [Coreboot docs on ACPI](https://doc.coreboot.org/acpi/index.html) but there is no meaningful information related to this case.

I also tried to boot with `acpi=off` mode and `pci=noacpi` in Grub settings but the first fails to boot system (blank screen hangs on boot) and the second makes os unusable (no mouse/trackpad/keyboard working).

Comment: This is almost certainly a coreboot issue. The idea of ACPI is that certain actions, e.g. pressing the power button, closing the lid, reading the battery status are different for every laptop but every OS needs to handle them.  So you have an abstract machine which each OS implements, and the laptop manufacturer provides the "program" as part of the boot rom. Linux does have a way to patch the tables. If you can find a BIOS image for your machine you might be able to extract the tables.

Comment: Typically, firmware updates are required to fix ACPI bugs.

Comment: @icarus thanks, I've added full `dmesg` output: https://pastebin.com/LtFsH6KD and it seems that tables are loaded (lines 42-66), but later (line 237) there is an error reading them? Anyway I have extracted tables with `acpidump` and `acpixtract` but not sure what to do with those (*.dat files).

Comment: Sorry I can't help you more,  it is years since I was working with them. The boot rom typically copies the tables from rom to ram and then fills in some magic locations in low memory to say where the tables are. The tables that you copied would be added to your build process for coreboot.